# What are the types of personal data?

Tags: gdpr

In the GDPR, the concept of **data categories** is used and examples of such categories are given. The concept of **data types** is also used, but I do not know what they are.

Example of data categories, Article 9(1), "Processing of special categories of personal data":

> Processing of personal data revealing racial or ethnic origin, political opinions, religious or philosophical beliefs, or trade union membership, and the processing of genetic data, biometric data for the purpose of uniquely identifying a natural person, data concerning health or data concerning a natural person's sex life or sexual orientation shall be prohibited.

So what are the types?

Article 28(3):

> 3. Processing by a processor shall be governed by a contract or other legal act under Union or Member State law, that is binding on the processor with regard to the controller and that sets out the subject-matter and duration of the processing, the nature and purpose of the processing, **the type of personal data** and categories of data subjects and the obligations and rights of the controller. That contract or other legal act shall stipulate, in particular, that the processor:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The "type" is the specific nature of the data to be processed

For example: name, date of birth, ID photograph, address, email, description, etc.

Comment: Article 28(3) indicates that a single type should be specified, not types. In this context, your type interpretation seems to be wrong, because the indication of a single type would not make sense.

Comment: In English, the plural of type is type or types